# PhotoShop Define Brush Preset

Tags: photoshop, brushes

I'm trying to make a brush that gives a sparkle effect.  It's just a circle brush with a cross in the middle.  Any way, when I try to define the brush preset, it says "Could not complete the command Define Brush Preset because the selected area is empty."  Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press CTRL + D and deselect whatever you have selected. If you attempt to define a brush preset without anything selected, it should turn the whole image into a brush, but if you are trying to make a selection then make sure that you are selected on the correct layer.